# Convert JSON to a sorted JSON which include JSONArrays in nested nodes

Tags: java, json, string, key-value, alphabetical

Here I would like to know that, how to convert a un-sorted `JSON` string to a sorted `JSON` string which include multiple `JSON` arrays as child elements. The sample un-sorted `JSON` string is given below,

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 22,
    "foods": [{
            "product": "apple",
            "price": 100
        }, {
            "fruit": "banana",
            "price": 100
        }
    ],

    "attributes": {
        "OBJECTID": "35",
        "FACILITYTYPE": "Pharmacy",
        "FACILITYSUBTYPE": "24 Hr Pharmacy",
        "COMMERCIALNAME_E": "SADD MAARAB PHARMACY"
    }
}
```

Expected output is as follows,

```
{
    "age": 22,
    "attributes": {
        "COMMERCIALNAME_E": "SADD MAARAB PHARMACY",
        "FACILITYSUBTYPE": "24 Hr Pharmacy",
        "FACILITYTYPE": "Pharmacy",
        "OBJECTID": "35"
    },
    "foods": [{
            "price": 100m
            "product": "apple"
        }, {
            "fruit": "banana",
            "price": 100
        }
    ],
    "name": "John",
}
```

Can someone help me to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Are you limited to some specific JSON library? For instance if you are using jackson this can interest you https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-property-order-annotation.html (see part about `@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = true)`)

Comment: So you're not making any modifications to the data, but just want it printed nicely?  If the order of the keys matters and changes your functionality then you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON Object` in `Java` can be represented by `Map<String, Object>` and `JSON Array` can be represented by `List`, `Set`, `array[]` or any other `Collection`. Most popular libraries like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) can do that by default. For `JSON Object` [documentation](https://www.json.org/) says:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

So, most libraries by default do not take care about order and used unordered `Map` implementations. At most they can keep order from `JSON` payload by using `LinkedHashMap` or any other similar implementation. But to force order we need to customise configuration.

For `Gson` it can look like this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TreeMapTypeAdapterFactory())
                .create();

        Map root = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Map.class);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(root));
    }
}

class TreeMapTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public final <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
            final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
            return createCustomTypeAdapter(delegate);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private <T> TypeAdapter<T> createCustomTypeAdapter(TypeAdapter<T> delegate) {
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                Map map = (Map) value;
                delegate.write(out, (T) new TreeMap(map));
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                return delegate.read(in);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

For `JSON` payload above app prints:

```
{
  "age": 22.0,
  "attributes": {
    "COMMERCIALNAME_E": "SADD MAARAB PHARMACY",
    "FACILITYSUBTYPE": "24 Hr Pharmacy",
    "FACILITYTYPE": "Pharmacy",
    "OBJECTID": "35"
  },
  "foods": [
    {
      "price": 100.0,
      "product": "apple"
    },
    {
      "fruit": "banana",
      "price": 100.0
    }
  ],
  "name": "John"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try little [json](https://github.com/antonsjava/json) library 
and this code 
(code can be more effective with one comparrator instance and you don't need to make copy of object and sort it on place.)

```
    private static JsonValue deepsort(JsonValue value) {
        if(value == null) return null;
        else if(value.isLiteral()) return value.copy();
        else if(value.isArray()) {
            JsonArray newarray = JsonFactory.array();
            for(JsonValue jsonValue : value.asArray().toList()) {
                newarray.add(deepsort(jsonValue));
            }
            return newarray;
        } else {
            JsonObject newobject = JsonFactory.object();
            List<JsonAttribute> attrs = value.asObject().toList();
            Collections.sort(attrs, new Comparator<JsonAttribute>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(JsonAttribute o1, JsonAttribute o2) {
                    return o1.name().stringValue().compareTo(o2.name().stringValue());
                }
            });
            for(JsonAttribute attr : attrs) {
                newobject.add(attr.name().stringValue(), deepsort(attr.value()));
            }
            return newobject;
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        String json = "{\n" +
"    \"name\": \"John\",\n" +
"    \"age\": 22,\n" +
"    \"foods\": [{\n" +
"            \"product\": \"apple\",\n" +
"            \"price\": 100\n" +
"        }, {\n" +
"            \"fruit\": \"banana\",\n" +
"            \"price\": 100\n" +
"        }\n" +
"    ],\n" +
"\n" +
"    \"attributes\": {\n" +
"        \"OBJECTID\": \"35\",\n" +
"        \"FACILITYTYPE\": \"Pharmacy\",\n" +
"        \"FACILITYSUBTYPE\": \"24 Hr Pharmacy\",\n" +
"        \"COMMERCIALNAME_E\": \"SADD MAARAB PHARMACY\"\n" +
"    }\n" +
"}";
        JsonValue v = JsonParser.parse(json);
        JsonValue newv = deepsort(v);
        System.out.println(newv.toPrettyString("  "));
    }
```